# List all symbolic links to themselves

Tags: python, symlink

I need to process the output of a certain program in Python. The output of that program contains several symlinks which  point to themselves, which can be a pain to work with.

I want to detect, from a list of files, which ones are symlinks pointing to themselves so that I can delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to properly detect recursive symlinks in `target_dir`:

```
import os

target_dir = os.getcwd()
all_files = [os.path.realpath(os.path.join(target_dir, f))
             for f in os.listdir(target_dir)]

for f in all_files:
    if os.path.islink(f) and os.path.realpath(os.readlink(f)) == f:
        print('%s is a recursive symlink' % f)
```

Comment: This is not recursive, this only examines the 1st level children files.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list and save to it paths of interesting files.
If you don't know them, maybe compare list of files in specific locations before and after running program.
You can read files from that list in a loop and check if some of them contain path from the list.
Problem could occur with reading symlinks, as they contain insides of what they point. There is a os.readlink() function which read symlink of itself. Symlink itself contain path to file it points.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` + `awk` to do the work.

Use `find` to list all symlinks:

```
$ find . -type l -ls
1197707      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 user  user         9 Mar  2 17:22 ./subdir/testlink2 -> testlink2
1183041      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 user  user         8 Mar  2 17:20 ./testlink -> testlink
```

If you only want to list symlinks from in current directory, apply a `-maxdepth` argument:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -ls
```

After listing all symlinks, use `awk` to find the ones pointing to itself:

```
$ find . -type l -ls | awk '{ n=split($11, a, "/"); if (a[n] == $13) { print $11 } }'
./subdir/testlink2
./testlink
```

Here I'm using some positional arguments, but they should not be hard to understand.